# Symfony3 - Change base URL to "/is"

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, routes, symfony-3.2

I'm new to Symfony3.

What should I do to change my base url `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/is/`?

The whole application should start from `/is/` path.

What I have done till now is,

routing.yml

```
user:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /is/

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

But didn't get success. Where am I wrong and what should I Do?

**Edit** - current behavior

Currently when I go to `https://example.com/is/` It is redirecting me to `https://example.com/login` because of `access_control` in `security.yml`.

If I type `https://example.com/is/login`, It shows me `404 Path not found` error.

Comment: What do you mean by "But didn't get success"? Please edit your question to explain the current behavior and what you expect.

Comment: @Kwadz please see my edited question.

Comment: But why do you want that?

Comment: @goto It is required because in base path `https://example.com/` we have to show the wordpress side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /is
```

Then you need to put the /login url behind IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY Or you will never access to login page when you are unlogged

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/is/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `routing.yml` use this yml:

```
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /is
```

See if that works.

---

EDIT #2

Also change security.yml like so:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/is/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/is/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Please see my `security.yml` I have used FOS user bundle for authentication. So if I type `/is` in my browser it is redirecting me to `/login`. What needs to be changed?(Tested by clearing cache). Please help.

Comment: See my updated edit. I think that should be all the changes? Try it.